# using nth-child(n) with scss and &:nth-child for giving children different classes

Tags: html, css, sass

I'm trying to do some css art stuff, I'm just colouring divs and making lines out of them. At first I was doing it like this

```
<a href='#'></a>
```

and styling via

```
[href*='#'] {
    &:after { ..css}
    &:after { ..css}
    &:after { ..css}
}
```

but it turns out you can't use more than 2 psuedo elements in css 3, I think?

So I turned to a new solution, because I'm expecting to use more than 3 child elements for the art. So I found out about :nth-child(n) selector,

so I thought I could go:

```
[href*='#'] {
&:nth-child(1) { ..css}
&:nth-child(2) { ..css}
&:nth-child(3) { ..css}
}
```

with the html looking like

```
<a href='#'>
<div></div>
<div></div>
<div></div>
</a>
```

but it only creates the first child style :o

Comment: Is this SASS or css?

Comment: a div:nth-child(1) { ..css }
a div:nth-child(2) { ..css }
a div:nth-child(3) { ..css }

see if this work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're not targeting the `divs`. Use:

```
<a href='#'>
  <div>1</div>
  <div>2</div>
  <div>3</div>
</a>
```

SCSS:

```
[href*='#']{
  >div{
    &:nth-child(1) { color: green }
    &:nth-child(2) { color: blue }
    &:nth-child(3) { color: red }
  }
}
```

[JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/6ma0of6s/)

Comment: yeah even just a { div { bla bla } } works. That is weird behavior isn't it? From the documentation I've been reading you're meant to use :nth-child on the parent of the children to select those children, not the actual children..???? Thank you though it worked :)

Comment: It depends what you need to select. `div {}` also works, but this will select every `div` in your DOM, so you have to be careful what are you doing. Here's a good article about `nth-child` - [How nth-child Works](https://css-tricks.com/how-nth-child-works/)

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the **&**, use it only when you want to create a more specific selector

```
[href*='#']  { &:nth-child(1)} => [href*='#']:nth-child(1){}
```

Here you need a space

```
[href*='#']  { :nth-child(1)} => [href*='#'] :nth-child(1){}



[href*='#']  { 
  :nth-child(1) { background-color: red;}
  :nth-child(2) { background-color: yellow;}
  :nth-child(3) { background-color: green;} 
}
```

```css
[href*='#'] :nth-child(1) { background-color: red;}

[href*='#'] :nth-child(2) { background-color: yellow;}

[href*='#'] :nth-child(3) { background-color: green;}
```

```html
with the html looking like

<a href='#'>
<div>One</div>
<div>Two</div>
<div>Three</div>
</a>
```